# sudo: n: command not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Trying to update my node version to the current lts version 16.18 on ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

ran well

```
sudo n lts
```

while trying to run the above command I get `sudo: n: command not found`

Comment: Try installing `n` with sudo and try again

Comment: How exactly did you run `n lts` and have `sudo` print an error message...?

Comment: already installed n on version 9.0.0